# Composing generators

Tags: javascript, generator

Given the following. I want to lazily apply `transform` to each member of the iterable returned from `Object.keys`.

How can I do this?

```
function* numbers(upto, transform) { 
  yield* Object.keys([...Array(upto)]); // How can `transform` be applied here lazily?
}

function timesTwo(n) {
    return n*2;
}

var generator = numbers(31, timesTwo)

for(var i of generator) {
    console.log(i); // 0 2 4 6 8... 60
}
```

Comment: That `transform` parameter makes it seem like you're happy to have the transform passed into `numbers` rather than composing them externally, is that correct?

Comment: Yes. Open to better ways too though

Comment: Was trying to create a simple example, but might have missed something. Developing my understanding in this area... IIUC The `yield*` means each value of the inner `iterable` is yielded. This fits a simplistic example as far as I can tell. I would imagine a real example might be a list of numbers too large to fit into memory.

Comment: Fantastic question.

Comment: You don't use `transform` in the body of the generator function... and the result is not as you have suggested, plus the `timesTwo` function doesn't return anything...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you're happy to have the transform passed into `numbers`, you can apply it as you generate if you take advantage of `numbers` being a generator:

```js
function* numbers(upto, transform) { 
  let n = 0;
  while (n < upto) {
      yield transform(n);
      ++n;
  }
}

const timesTwo = n => n * 2;

const generator = numbers(31, timesTwo);

for (const i of generator) {
    console.log(i); // 0 2 4 6 8... 60
}
```

[Live on Babel's REPL](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Ces2016%2Ces2017%2Creact%2Cstage-2%2Cstage-3&experimental=false&loose=false&spec=false&code=function*%20numbers(upto%2C%20transform)%20%7B%20%0A%20%20let%20n%20%3D%200%3B%0A%20%20while%20(n%20%3C%20upto)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20yield%20transform(n)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%2B%2Bn%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aconst%20timesTwo%20%3D%20n%20%3D%3E%20n%20*%202%3B%0A%0Aconst%20generator%20%3D%20numbers(31%2C%20timesTwo)%3B%0A%0Afor%20(const%20i%20of%20generator)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(i)%3B%20%2F%2F%200%202%204%206%208...%2060%0A%7D&playground=false) for those whose browsers won't run the above.

---

We *could* use your original definition of `numbers`, but we'd either have to apply the transform eagerly instead of lazily, or we'd have to use the array's iterator (the array will be created all at once regardless). Here's that latter one:

```js
function* numbers(upto, transform) { 
  for (const n of Object.keys([...Array(upto)])) {
    yield transform(n);
  }
}

const timesTwo = n => n * 2;

const generator = numbers(31, timesTwo);

for (const i of generator) {
    console.log(i); // 0 2 4 6 8... 60
}
```

[Live on Babel's REPL](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Ces2016%2Ces2017%2Creact%2Cstage-2%2Cstage-3&experimental=false&loose=false&spec=false&code=function*%20numbers(upto%2C%20transform)%20%7B%20%0A%20%20for%20(const%20n%20of%20Object.keys(%5B...Array(upto)%5D))%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20yield%20transform(n)%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aconst%20timesTwo%20%3D%20n%20%3D%3E%20n%20*%202%3B%0A%0Aconst%20generator%20%3D%20numbers(31%2C%20timesTwo)%3B%0A%0Afor%20(const%20i%20of%20generator)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(i)%3B%20%2F%2F%200%202%204%206%208...%2060%0A%7D&playground=false).

---

We could separate out the two aspects of `numbers` there and have a general-purpose `transform` function that is basically the generator version of `map`:

```
function* transform(iterable, f) {
  for (const v of iterable) {
    yield f(v);
  }
}
```

Then we can use that on a more basic `numbers`:

```js
function* transform(iterable, f) {
  for (const v of iterable) {
    yield f(v);
  }
}

function* numbers(upto) { 
  yield* Object.keys([...Array(upto)]);
}

const timesTwo = n => n * 2;

const generator = transform(numbers(31), timesTwo);

for (const i of generator) {
    console.log(i); // 0 2 4 6 8... 60
}
```

[On Babel's REPL](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Ces2016%2Ces2017%2Creact%2Cstage-2%2Cstage-3&experimental=false&loose=false&spec=false&code=function*%20transform(iterable%2C%20f)%20%7B%0A%20%20for%20(const%20v%20of%20iterable)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20yield%20f(v)%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Afunction*%20numbers(upto)%20%7B%20%0A%20%20yield*%20Object.keys(%5B...Array(upto)%5D)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aconst%20timesTwo%20%3D%20n%20%3D%3E%20n%20*%202%3B%0A%0Aconst%20generator%20%3D%20transform(numbers(31)%2C%20timesTwo)%3B%0A%0Afor%20(const%20i%20of%20generator)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(i)%3B%20%2F%2F%200%202%204%206%208...%2060%0A%7D&playground=false)

---

Side note: I'm sure *you* know this, but for any lurkers, the `numbers` in the question [and a couple of them below] iterates over a series of *strings*: `"0"`, `"1"`, etc. But then when we multiply with them, they get coerced to numbers. To actually have a series of numbers based on the question's `numbers` approach, we'd need

```
yield* Object.keys([...Array(upto)]).map(Number));
```

Comment: Presumably if I want a lazy transform with the delegation I need to construct a new iterable within which the transform is lazily performed.

Comment: @BenAston: Exactly. That's what I did in my second example above, then I went back just now and separated it out in the third.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function lazy(f) {
    return function*(iter) {
        for(const v of iter) {
            yield f(v);
        }
    }
}

function* numbers(upto, transform) { 
    yield* lazy(transform)(Object.keys([...Array(upto)]));
}

function timesTwo(n) {
    console.log('times two called on ', n);
    return n*2;
}

var generator = numbers(11, timesTwo)

for(var i of generator) {
    console.log(i); // 0 2 4 6 8... 20
}
```